# Excel 2010 BuildFreeForm Has NO Connection Points

Tags: excel-2010

When I use VBA to create a rectangle similar to one I draw on a worksheet, whay are there no connection points? After adding the last node I use ConvertToShape. It doesn't matter if I use msoEditingAuto or msoEditingCorner for all of the points. I can make the connection points available only if I use SetPosition on one of the nodes and use the existing position.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It would be helpful if you could add the code you are using to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The following code from Microsoft's [object reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa196410%28v=office.11%29.aspx) gives an example of using connector points with rectangles:

```
Sub buildshape3()

   Dim myDocument As Worksheet
   Dim s As Object
   Dim firstRect As Shape
   Dim secondRect As Shape
   Dim c As Shape

   Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
   Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes
   Set firstRect = s.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 100, 150, 150, 150) '50, 200, 100)

   firstRect.Fill.Transparency = 1
   Set secondRect = s.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 300, 300, 200, 100)
   Set c = s.AddConnector(msoConnectorCurve, 0, 0, 100, 100)
   With c.ConnectorFormat
      .BeginConnect ConnectedShape:=firstRect, ConnectionSite:=1
      .EndConnect ConnectedShape:=secondRect, ConnectionSite:=1
      c.RerouteConnections
   End With

End Sub
```